# Why do you get "Saving changes is not permitted" when changing the length of an nvchar column in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

According to this:

[Microsoft description of how SQL works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/ssms/error-when-you-save-table)

> This problem occurs when you make one or more of the following changes
> to the table: You change the Allow Nulls setting for a column. You
> reorder columns in the table. You change the column data type. You add
> a new column. You change the filegroup of a table or its text/image
> data.

I tried changing the max length of a nvchar from 25 to 100 on a column and it won't let me save it.

It is not at all listed as being one of the conditions under which this error should be presented.

Can anyone tell me why SSMS 18 is doing this to me?

Comment: What is the SQL you're running to get this error? Changing the length of a string column (to a longer length) isn't something that would normally be blocked; unless the column is being used as a foreign key candidate.

Comment: I just went into designer and changed it from 25 to 100 and told it to save. When I try to change it with a query it says this: Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object 'SSMA_CC$Table$City$disallow_zero_length' is dependent on column 'City'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN City failed because one or more objects access this column.

Comment: Don't use the designer. `ALTER` the column.

Comment: WEll, there you go, @ZCT , there are dependencies; as I alluded to in my original comment. You'll need to `DROP` those dependencies, `ALTER` the column, and then recreate them.

Answer (score 1):

The article you linked to *explains what the issue is*.

SSMS has a safeguard built in that prevents you saving changing where its script would drop and re-create the table.

Sometimes SSMS can be overly cautious and it's not even necessary.

You can (and probably should) use the `alter table` syntax directly, however you can disable this behaviour in SSMS by going to:

`tools > options > Designers > Table and Database Desingners`

and then untick the option `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for dependencies (i.e. Foreign Keys)
2. Use ALTER, for example

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]( [aaa] nchar NULL) ON [PRIMARY] GO

   ALTER TABLE Test ALTER COLUMN aaa NCHAR(100)

SSMS is quite quirky when it comes to database objects.